# Can you intercept hyperlink clicks with FireMonkey (cross platform)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a TWebBrowser on a FireMonkey app (Android and iOS).

I'd like to be able to intercept (trap) hyperlink clicks in the TWebBrowser and do something different with them.

I've found references to working with the BeforeNavigate2 event. However, I see no way of adding a procedure for that event in the Object Inspector. And I'm not sure if that event exists for Android or iOS; or if it's just a Windows event.

Is there any way to get to intercept hyperlink clicks cross platform?

[Edit]

My ultimate goal here is to intercept a hyperlink click in the browser component and do something different with it (e.g., I'd like to spawn it off to the native browser instead).

`OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest` doesn't trigger on a click. Actually it doesn't seem to trigger anywhere for me. Others have had this issue [(Incus J)](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=700532).

`OnDidStartLoad` does trigger; however, it appears to carry on with the page load in the background regardless of what's going on in the trigger. I can add a `myWebBrowser.Stop` in the trigger; however, it does not reliably work. I suspect that sometimes the page load completes before the `Stop` gets fired off.

Playing with `OnDidFinishLoad` and using the `GoBack` method proved awkward because the previous page would reload to the top of the page instead of what was being shown in the control (if the user scrolled).

Am I stuck trying to hack Android/iOS equivalents of TWindowsWebBrowserService as  [Incus J](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=700532) suggests in the thread I reference above?

Comment: Is the documentation of any help: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser

Comment: Nothing that's obvious to me... BeforeNavigate2 doesn't exists as one of the events - my hope is that there's an alternate method available.

Comment: OnDidStartLoad http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.OnDidStartLoad or OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TCustomWebBrowser.OnShouldStartLoadWithRequest  Did you look through the events?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my question since the reasons why they don't work.

Comment: @BIBD Old thread, but I'm running into the same problem, under RAD Studio Berlin 10.1. Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @MiguelE Sorry, no better luck. I ended up changing the design of the App to avoid the problem.

Comment: @BIBD thanks. I've been trying TMSFMXWebBrowser. Still some minor problems, but I think it will solve this.